# Page Transitions Break When Not Using jQuery Mobile Stylesheet in Chrome / Safari

Tags: jquery, mobile, stylesheet, break, transition

I've noticed when using jQuery Mobile if you don't use the jQuery Mobile stylesheet - you can't move from one page to another when using a webkit browser such as Chrome or Safari - Firefox and IE are fine.

Is there any way of fixing this?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who reads this thread and runs into the same problem, I removed the line:

```
cssTransitions: "WebKitTransitionEvent" in window,
```

From:

$.extend( $.support, {
    orientation: "orientation" in window,
    touch: "ontouchend" in document,
    cssTransitions: "WebKitTransitionEvent" in window,
    pushState: !!history.pushState,
    mediaquery: $.mobile.media('only all'),
    cssPseudoElement: !!propExists('content'),
    boxShadow: !!propExists('boxShadow') && !bb,
    scrollTop: ("pageXOffset" in window || "scrollTop" in document.documentElement || "scrollTop" in fakeBody[0]) && !webos,
    dynamicBaseTag: baseTagTest(),
    eventCapture: ("addEventListener" in document) // This is a weak test. We may want to beef this up later.
});

to disable css transitions in webkit browsers. Hope this of use to others.